# Difference between [...obj] and {...obj}

Tags: javascript, object-destructuring

I know about the spread operator `...` in JavaScript. We can use it on both arrays and objects:

```js
let user = {
  name: "aman",
  rollno: 11
}

let newobj1 = {...user}
let newobj2 = [...user]
console.log(newobj1)
console.log(newobj2)
```

Why does `newobj2` give an error, `TypeError: user is not iterable`, but `newobj1` works fine?

Comment: What error is this code generating? You didn't include that information in your question 

Comment: What did you _expect_ from spreading an object into an array?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought that we can spread an object in an array and all the key-value pairs of the object will become elements of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{...user}` just creates a new object with the same properties as `user`.

`[...user]`, on the other hand, iterates through the object and adds the values it finds into the array it returns. If there is no way to iterate, as there isn't by default on a plain object (as opposed to an array), then this doesn't work and raises the error you've quoted.

As always, there is much more information about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Note in particular the [following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#only_for_iterables) section:

> Spread syntax (other than in the case of spread properties) can only
> be applied to iterable objects like `Array`, or with iterating
> functions such as `map()`, `reduce()`, and `assign()`.
>
> Many objects are not iterable, including `Object`:
>
> ```
> let obj = {'key1': 'value1'};
> let array = [...obj]; // TypeError: obj is not iterable
> ```
>
> To use spread syntax with these objects, you will need to provide an
> iterator function.

And note that the "spread syntax"  being referred to here is the "array spread" version. "Object spread" is rather different and explained on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) part of the page,

Comment: Thanks. This helped me understand the difference between the use of spread operators w.r.t. objects and array. 
if x is an array then
let y = [...x] is also valid
and let y = {...x} is also valid
but if x is an object then
let y = {...x} is valid
yet y = [...x] is invalid

Answer (score 0):

> {...user}

means that you create new object and spread all the data from `user` inside it.

When you suppose to execute

> [...user]

you tries to create brand new array and then spread the `user` object inside.